# Is it possible to set up AMQP message properties in outgoing message?

Tags: spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitMQ binder. I need to call external service which does not use Spring Cloud Stream. This service is using `type` and `correlation_id` message properties.

I tried to set headers in outgoing message but, even though properties, technically are headers, they are treated in special way. So setting `type` header does not set a property.

I am aware about interceptors and, if using only Spring RabbitMq, it would not be a problem. But since Spring Cloud Stream represents higher level of abstraction, all binder specific settings are hidden.

Is there any possibility to set up RabbitMQ properties in outgoing stream message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties are mapped from message headers keyed by `AmqpHeaders` constants; in this case `AmqpHeaders.TYPE` (`amqp_type`) and `AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID` (`amqp_correlationId`).

All "unknown" message headers are mapped as rabbit headers.

Comment: Just double checked... Type works fine, but correlation id seems to be missing. I am building a message with `.setHeader(AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlationId)`

Comment: Follow up comment: Correlation id is used by library internals, so you can't use it by your own.

Comment: If you mean the `RabbitTemplate` - see property `correlationKey` which instructs the framework to use a different header for correlation - of course the receiving side need to know that too.